# Best way to store Business Availability (Weekday and Time) with possible varing timezones

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently developing a work availability calendar for users. And I'm looking for a way to store weekly availability so it can be transformed depending on the timezone. For example:

If I store Monday with availability from 4 p.m. to 10 p.m. (GMT -5), it should transform the availability from 9 p.m. Monday to 3 a.m Tuesday when being saved on UTC. However, as it is currently set, it is available.

To summarize, is there any way to store this availability in UTC and then transform it to the desired timezone or receive it on a different timezone and then store it in UTC, taking into account the changes in days from one day to another?

Initially, I was thinking on storing the availability with two TimeFields for the start_time and end_time and a CharField storing the day of the week. However, when converting the times to UTC, they may change from one day to another. And like that I will not be aware if the days change.

Note: Sorry about my grammar.